# drupal after language import word not found or duplicated enrty

Tags: drupal, lang, drupal-5

I got Drupal 5 with instalated with Hungarian Language.

I want use this site with several lanugage.
I downloaded several language from drupal translate site and import it with admin.
In Admin locale I can change the language.

So i've got : Greek,Czech,Hungarian,English Language in my site.

I begin to translate all the string that is not traslated.

In Greek Po file i use the Drupal Greek po header

```
# Greek translation of Drupal core (5.23)
# Copyright (c) 2011 by the Greek translation team
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Drupal core (5.23)\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2011-06-23 08:28+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM+ZZZZ\n"
"Language-Team: Greek\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n!=1);\n"
```

And the right sintax.

I import the my custom .po file to GreeK languge with overWrite old options.

But Drupal don't translate my words.

In .po file i use  Hungarian words for msgId and Greek words for msgStr

```
msgid "Algéria"
msgstr "Αλγερία"
```

I check in drupal "admin/settings/locale/string/search" that the word is presented in
 **en,hu locale** and missing in **el (Greek) locale**.

So i added the HU translation, after that to word is translated.

I use hungarian words in the t() function.

I googled for this some time.

I think that .po file must be in EN->XY language format, but i can't find any information about this.

How can i use hungarian Word in t() function with custom .po file to import?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer:
No.

t() function in D5 and other drupal, can use only English string int t() function.

If there is no english word it make translation error.

So t() function and translation use english as base.

So the manualy edit os not good for english language.